# HTML email <td> height issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, email

I'm coding a HTML e-mail but i run into a problem with the following HTML:

```
<table width="510" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" width="30" valign="top"><img src="http://www.dmxs.nl/upc/Luiaard/UPC5_08.jpg" alt="Voor slecht € 28,20 per maand" style="display:block;" border="0" /></td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="455" bgcolor="#fff209" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;" align="left"><span style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Titel</strong></span><br /><br />

<strong>- kop 1</strong><br /> 
<strong>- kop2</strong><br />
      <span style="margin-left:20px;">• mini1<br />
      </span>
      <span style="margin-left:20px;">• mini2<br />
      </span>
      <span style="margin-left:20px;">• mini3<br />
      </span>
<strong>- kop3<span style="text-decoration:none;"></span></strong><br />
<br />
<a href="####" style="border:none; text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.dmxs.nl/upc/Luiaard/UPC4_14.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="141" /></a></td>
    <td colspan="6" width="25" height="72" valign="top"><img src="http://www.dmxs.nl/upc/Luiaard/UPC5_10.jpg" alt="Voor slecht € 28,20 per maand" style="display:block;" border="0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="5"  bgcolor="#e7e7e8" style="font-size:1px; width:5px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#e7e7e8" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#dededf" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#cbcbcc" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#b0b0b1" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#8b8b8b" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20" bgcolor="#fff209"></td>
    <td width="20" bgcolor="#fff209"></td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#8f8e81" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#adadae" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#cacacb" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#ddddde" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1"  bgcolor="#e6e6e7" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Chrome and Firefox this works great however in Internet explorer the following part ain't working (not showing).

```
<td width="5"  bgcolor="#e7e7e8" style="font-size:1px; width:5px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#e7e7e8" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#dededf" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#cbcbcc" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#b0b0b1" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#8b8b8b" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="20" bgcolor="#fff209"></td>
        <td width="20" bgcolor="#fff209"></td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#8f8e81" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#adadae" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#cacacb" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#ddddde" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1"  bgcolor="#e6e6e7" style="font-size:1px; width:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
```

Does anybody had a solution for this problem(and no, we can't set the height static)?

[Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/eeJty/)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, because I don't use IE. IE sucks. I do know that you can remove all the "width"-tags, because you declared the width of the elements in your "style"-tag. That's no solution to your problem, but it makes your code look better.

Answer (score 0):

Put `&nbsp;` in your 2 empty table cells.

Explorer/Outlook are known to collapse empty table cells, which for some reason is preventing the rest of the row from rendering.